# $id: name of file, date/time creation Exp $

Tags: svn, version-control, perforce, cvs, rcs

Frequently I come across the following statements in C/C++ source code:

```
$Id: lzio.c,v 1.24 2003/03/20 16:00:56 roberto Exp $

$Id: file name, version, timestamp, creator Exp $
```

Have you got any idea which software produces those "signatures"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Version control systems such as CVS can produce such tags.

Comment: I think that probably most tools do support including CVS, SVN (subversion), Perforce, Git, Mercurial.

Answer (score 8):

[Keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) in subversion produces this sort of information, in particular Id:

> Id
>
> This keyword is a compressed combination of the other keywords. Its
>   substitution looks something like $Id:
>   calc.c 148 2006-07-28 21:30:43Z sally
>   $, and is interpreted to mean that the
>   file calc.c was last changed in
>   revision 148 on the evening of July
>   28, 2006 by the user sally.

You can tell subversion to insert these values using svn:keywords

> To tell Subversion whether or not to
>   substitute keywords on a particular
>   file, we again turn to the
>   property-related subcommands. The
>   svn:keywords property, when set on a
>   versioned file, controls which
>   keywords will be substituted on that
>   file. The value is a space-delimited
>   list of the keyword names or aliases
>   found in the previous table

You can also make these substitutions automatic by editing your config:

> Subversion also provides the
>   auto-props feature, which allows you
>   to create mappings of filename
>   patterns to property names and values.
>   These mappings are made in your
>   runtime configuration area. They again
>   affect adds and imports, and not only
>   can override any default MIME type
>   decision made by Subversion during
>   those operations, they can also set
>   additional Subversion or custom
>   properties, too. For example, you
>   might create a mapping that says that
>   any time you add JPEG files—ones that
>   match the pattern *.jpg—Subversion
>   should automatically set the
>   svn:mime-type property on those files
>   to image/jpeg. Or perhaps any files
>   that match *.cpp should have
>   svn:eol-style set to native, and
>   svn:keywords  set to Id. Auto-prop
>   support is perhaps the handiest
>   property related tool in the
>   Subversion toolbox. See the section
>   called “Config” for more about
>   configuring that support.

Answer (score 4):

Both RCS and CVS produce strings that look exactly like that.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a few vim setups that will auto-magically populate these values. SVN can grab these values on pre and post commit hooks to fill default information in commit logs.

Answer (score 1):

[Perforce](http://www.perforce.com) supports some (not sure about all) of those key words.